# Custom, refreshing view not responding to OnClick

Tags: android, view, onclick

I made a view that contains a bar graph, which for now is fueled by random numbers generator and refreshes once a second. The idea is that after clicking one of the bars, it would change to a line graph.
This is code of the view:

```
public class BarGraph extends View implements OnClickListener{

private Paint paint;
private String[] horlabels;
private String[] verlabels;
private String title;
private int[] values;
Context co;
private RectF[] rects;

public BarGraph(Context context, String title, String[] hor, String[] var) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    if (title == null)
        title = "";
    else
        this.title = title;
    if (hor == null)
        this.horlabels = new String[0];
    else
        this.horlabels = hor;
    if (var == null)
        this.verlabels = new String[0];
    else
        this.verlabels = var;
    paint = new Paint();
    co = context;
}

public void updateVals(int[] vals){
    values = vals;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float border = 20;
    float horstart = border;
    float height = getHeight();
    float width = getWidth() - 1;
    int max = 100;
    int min = 0;
    float diff = max - min;
    float graphheight = height - (2 * border);
    float graphwidth = width - (2 * border);
    rects = new RectF[horlabels.length];
    this.setClickable(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    int vers = verlabels.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < verlabels.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        float y = ((graphheight / vers) * i) + border;
        canvas.drawLine(horstart, y, width - border, y, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText(verlabels[verlabels.length - 1 - i], 0, y, paint);
    }
    int hors = horlabels.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < horlabels.length + 1; i++) {
        paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
        canvas.drawLine(x, height - border, x, border, paint);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        if (i==horlabels.length-1)
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        if (i==0)
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < horlabels.length; i++)
    {
        float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
        canvas.drawText(horlabels[i], x + (graphwidth / (2*hors)), height - 4, paint);
    }

    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(title , (graphwidth / 2) + horstart, border - 4, paint);

    if (max != min) {
        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        float datalength = values.length;
        float colwidth = (width - (2 * border)) / datalength;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            float val = values[i] - min;
            float rat = val / diff;
            float h = graphheight * rat;
            RectF r = new RectF((i * colwidth) + horstart, (border - h) + graphheight, ((i * colwidth) + horstart) + (colwidth - 1), height - (border - 1));
            rects[i] = r;
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);      
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] coords = new int[2];
    v.getLocationInWindow(coords);
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(co, "KLIKNIETO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
    for(RectF r : rects){
        if(r.contains(coords[1], coords[2]))
        {
            try {
                this.finalize();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

It's started in this activity:

```
public class GraphTestActivity extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

 public  List<DataSet> sets;
 String[] verlabels;
 int[] vals;
 BarGraph graph;
 Thread t1;
 String[] hortable;
// private Updater task;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sets = new LinkedList<DataSet>();
    verlabels = new String[] {"0", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100"};
    DataSet set1 = new DataSet("set1");
    DataSet set2 = new DataSet("set2");
    DataSet set3 = new DataSet("set3");
    DataSet set4 = new DataSet("set4");
    DataSet set5 = new DataSet("set5");
    sets.add(set1);
    sets.add(set2);
    sets.add(set3);
    sets.add(set4);
    sets.add(set5);
    hortable = new String[sets.size()];
    vals = new int[sets.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++)
    {
        hortable[i] = sets.get(i).getName();
    }
    graph = new BarGraph(this, "Diagram slupkowy", hortable, verlabels);
    for(DataSet d : sets)
    {
        d.nextGen();
    }
    graph.updateVals(vals);
    setContentView(graph);
    new Updater().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    new BarRefresh().execute();     
}

class Updater extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // doSomething();
        while(true){
            for(DataSet d : sets)
            {
                d.nextGen();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(isCancelled()){
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class BarRefresh extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // doSomething();
        while(true){
            for(int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++)
            {
                vals[i] = sets.get(i).getLast();
            }
            graph.updateVals(vals);
            graph.postInvalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(isCancelled()){
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    try {
        this.finish();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, it does not react to touch. Could it have something to do with the way I set up refreshing in BarRefresh task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your BarGraph View Class is the one that you want to be clicking, you should make it HAVE an OnClickListener, instead of BEING an OnClickListener.

Here's what you do

1 remove the implements OnClickListener()

2 do something in your Activity like

```
bargraph.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //do whatever
}});
```

or you can put that code chunk inside the constructor (this.setOnClickListener()) so that all your BarGraph classes get it etc.